# jQuery focus() and select() not working in Firefox but works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, focus

I am trying to validate an input statement and if the input is wrong the user gets a Bubble Div informing that the input is incorrect. I am trying to revert the focus back to the errored input element and select the text inside it. The code works for Chrome but not in Firefox. Can anyone help me with this? . I am posting the code here :

```
$("#inner-tbl").on('blur', 'input[type=text]', function(e) {
    var checkval = $(this).val();
    checkval = checkval.replace(/\s/g,'');
    $(this).val(checkval);
    console.log(checkval);
    var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
    if(!numericReg.test(checkval)) {
        $(this).addClass("error");
        $(this).focus().select();
        console.log("Not an integer");
        var ip_width, ip_height, x;
        ip_width = $(this).outerWidth();
        ip_height = $(this).outerHeight();
        x = $(this).offset();
        console.log("Width :"+ip_width+" Height :"+ip_height+" Top :"+x.top+" Left :"+x.left);
        $("body").append("<div class='error_bubble'><span class='errordiv'>Numeric value.</span></div>");
        $(".error_bubble").css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: (x.top+30)+'px',
            left: (x.left-30)+'px'
        });
    } 
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neoragex/Wk35w/

Comment: Can you please show a working demo or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Added the fiddle :)

Comment: After searching for like 6-7 hrs i found something that seemed useful at first but apparently it was much troubling. The temp solution is to specify a setTimeout function and ask it to execute really fast. setTimeout ( function() { $(this).focus(); }, 1 );. This thing keeps on going into a Loop ????????????????

Comment: M already pulling my Hair and i have absolutely zero idea about whats happening with Mozilla.

Comment: It is working perfectly fine with Mozilla. Can't understand what is the exact problem you are facing! :(

Comment: @PraveenKumar Which version of Firefox are you using D: ? When i enter a character in the input field. It shows me the error but the input element thats in question isnt focused instead the next element is being focused.

Comment: It doesnt work on the latest version either. I have found a work around by using the setTimeout function and it seems to work fine now :). Thanks for the help :).

Comment: Nice... :) Good that it is working. But let this question as is, so as to find what is the issue! :)

Comment: Not working in Firefox 14.0.1 :(

Answer (score 0):

in Chrome & IE, text input field is focused and High-lighted

in Firefox, text input field is focused but cursor at beginning of unhighlighted text

```
$("#surname").focus();
$("#surname").select(); // for Firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use return false and its working me for firefox.

```
        $(this).focus().select();
        return false;
```